# 2-3-4 Tree Deletion Operation

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

How can I delete the node 1 from 2-3-4 Tree if the tree's structure is as below:

```
            4      10
        /       |       \
      2        6,8      12,14 
    /  \     /  |  \   /   |   \
   1   3    5   7  9  11  13   15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I like to think of it, you only delete leaves or internal nodes that have a single child, and the children of whatever you delete have to stay the same level.

This requires pulling a key down from the level above to hold them, which merges with a sibling.

If the parent only has one key, this will cause a cascaded delete.

```
Deleting 1 by pulling down 2 causes a cascaded delete:
     
      4 ,  10
  /     |      \
 X     6,8      12,14
 |    / | \     / |  \
2,3  5  7  9  11  13  15

The cascaded delete pulls down the 4:
     
           10
         /    \
    4,6,8      12,14
   / | | \     / |  \
2,3  5 7  9  11  13  15
```

If the sibling is too big to merge, you may have to redistribute from the sibling.  This would be required if this was a 2-3 tree, for example:

```
Redistributing a key from 6,8
     
        6  ,  10
     /     |      \
    4      8      12,14
   / \    / \     / |  \
2,3   5  7   9  11  13  15
```